# Problem with Boost Fibonacci Heap at the moment of erasing an element

Tags: c++, boost, fibonacci-heap

I'm getting an unrelated error with Boost's Fibonacci Heap when I use the `erase()`method:

```
astar: /usr/include/boost/intrusive/list.hpp:1266: static boost::intrusive::list_impl<ValueTraits, SizeType, ConstantTimeSize, HeaderHolder>::iterator boost::intrusive::list_impl<ValueTraits, SizeType, ConstantTimeSize, HeaderHolder>::s_iterator_to(boost::intrusive::list_impl<ValueTraits, SizeType, ConstantTimeSize, HeaderHolder>::reference) [with ValueTraits = boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::heap::detail::heap_node_base<false>, boost::intrusive::list_node_traits<void*>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)1, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 1>; SizeType = long unsigned int; bool ConstantTimeSize = true; HeaderHolder = void; boost::intrusive::list_impl<ValueTraits, SizeType, ConstantTimeSize, HeaderHolder>::iterator = boost::intrusive::list_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::heap::detail::heap_node_base<false>, boost::intrusive::list_node_traits<void*>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)1, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 1>, false>; boost::intrusive::list_impl<ValueTraits, SizeType, ConstantTimeSize, HeaderHolder>::reference = boost::heap::detail::heap_node_base<false>&]: Assertion `!node_algorithms::inited(value_traits::to_node_ptr(value))' failed.
```

This is the part of the code that triggers the error:

```
void prune(Node_h* last_sol){
    Node_h* elem;
    int count = 0;
    for(auto it=open.begin(),end=open.end(); it != end; ++it){
        elem = *it;
        
        if (handlers.find(elem) == handlers.end()){
            printf("KEEEEY NOT FOUND");
        } else {
            printf("elem->f: %f >= last_sol->f: %f \n",elem->g.second+elem->h.second, last_sol->g.second+last_sol->h.second);
            if(elem->g.second+elem->h.second >= last_sol->g.second+last_sol->h.second){ 
                
                open.erase(handlers[elem]);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("New Open size: %ld ", open.size());
    printf("Nodes prune: %d\n", count);
}
```

I'm saving the handlers in a hash map at the moment of pushing the nodes:

```
open_handle handler = open.push(succ);
handlers[succ] = handler;
```

Everything worked fine with the heap until this point (pop and push methods) so I'm puzzled on what could trigger this error, implementation looks accord to the documentation.

Other information:

```
struct compare_states {
    bool operator()(const Node_h* s1, const Node_h* s2) const {
        //return n1.id > n2.id;
        return s1->f > s2->f ;
    }
};
typedef fibonacci_heap<Node_h*,compare<compare_states> >::handle_type open_handle;
```

gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

Comment: *"an unrelated error"* -- unrelated to what? It seems very much related to your question, considering it appears to be the focus of your question.

Comment: One characteristic of a [mre] is that it can be copied and compiled to reproduce the error. Your code does not meet that criterion. (Just don't go overboard, since "minimal" is also a goal. Don't get frustrated and dump your entire program into the question, like some people have done.)

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo, I was in a bit of a rush when I created the question so I was planing on adding a reproducible example today but @sehe nailed it with that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop looks suspect:

```
for(auto it=open.begin(),end=open.end(); it != end; ++it){
    open.erase(/*...*/);
}
```

Quoting [the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/heap/concepts.html#:%7E:text=Unless%20otherwise%20noted%2C%20all%20non%2Dconst%20heap%20member%20functions%20invalidate%20iterators):

> ***Unless otherwise noted, all non-const heap member functions invalidate iterators***, while all const member functions preserve the iterator validity.

That means the `erase` invalidates the loop iterator(s).

From context I'm assuming that `handler`/`handlers` in your code actually refers to node `handle`s. If so, you might want to collect handles to be erased in a temporary container before doing the deletion:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/8edfeW4j1)**

```
#include <boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <map>

int main() {
    namespace bh = boost::heap;
    using Heap   = bh::fibonacci_heap<int>;
    using Handle = Heap::handle_type;

    Heap open;
    std::map<int, Heap::handle_type> handles;

    for (int j : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
        handles.emplace(j, open.push({j}));

    std::vector<Handle> to_erase;
    for (int el : open) {
        if (el % 2) {
            //if (handles.contains(el)) {
                to_erase.push_back(handles.at(el));
            //}
        }
    }

    fmt::print("Deleting {} odd elements from {}\n", to_erase.size(), open);
    for (auto h : to_erase)
        open.erase(h);

    fmt::print("Remaining {}\n", open);
}
```

Prints

```
Deleting 3 odd elements from [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Remaining [4, 2]
```

---

For classic node-based containers, the following loop style would be applicable:

```
for (auto it = open.begin(), end = open.end(); it != end;) {
    if (condition) 
        it = open.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

However, `fibonacci_heap::erase` returns void.

> In fact this algorithm is standardized as [the free function `std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) in c++20 for standard containers.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. The iterator was being invalidated and gave me that error. Deleting after traversing the heap worked for me. When you mean classic node-based containers is saving the handler inside the node struct ?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Classic node-based containers don't have a distinction between handle and node reference, making the interface more straightforward.